# Python - Map coordinates into list of lines and arcs

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates, line, automatic-ref-counting

i'm trying to parse an array of coordinates (which represents a closed shape) into a set of lines and arcs in python (I'm using OpenCV for edge detection).

What I'm trying to achieve, briefly, is to use the coordinates which draw this example image

[Example shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s34I0.png)

Into this set of lines and arcs

[Set of arcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6o7X.png)

Obviously, arcs are not so defined as in the image, but are something like "pixeled" arcs.

Is there any utility which can help with this kind of processing?

Comment: you could start by calculating the curvature in every point, which is basically the angle. perhaps smooth it, in case you have a dense contour where points are either adjacent or on the nearest diagonal pixel... which would give you "noisy" data. plot the curvature magnitudes. you'll see that straight lines have none (near 0) and circles/arcs have a constant curvature. ellipses are tricky. from that curvature info, you can cut your contour into pieces, because you can make out segments of equal curvature. curvature is the first derivative. you could go further, take the second derivative too

Comment: Do you need a solution for this shape only or do you want a program that can vectorize any shape? If you need a general approach, you should look into the library `linedraw`. If it's just this one shape, it should be relatively easy to decompose it to just horizontal and vertical lines, substitute the rest with rectangles and compute the 90° arches with the radii given by their sides.

Comment: Threshold the image to black and white, use Canny edge detection, then Hough transform to find the straight lines. Draw the found lines on a separate binary image with thickness roughly equal to the lines in your image, then take the binary AND of that image and your original thresholded image - that's going to be the pixels covered by your straight lines, every other non-black pixel would belong to an arc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's load the image as grayscale, threshold it to black and white and invert colors, erode it a little, use Canny edge detection, then Hough lines detection (mostly just following [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import random

src = cv2.imread("s34I0.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thr, bw = cv2.threshold(src, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
eroded = cv2.erode(bw, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
canny = cv2.Canny(src, 50, 200, None, 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(canny, 1, np.pi / 180, 150, None, 0, 0)
lines = [list(x[0]) for x in lines]

def draw_line(img, line, color, thickness):
    rho, the = line
    a   = math.cos(the)
    b   = math.sin(the)
    x0  = a * rho
    y0  = b * rho
    pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000 * (-b)), int(y0 + 1000 * (a)))
    pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000 * (-b)), int(y0 - 1000 * (a)))

    cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

[image]

We have, unfortunately, two parallel lines detected for every straight segment. Let's replace each such pair of close parallel lines with their mid-line:

```
lines_ = []

def midline(line1, line2):
    return [(x + y) / 2 for x, y in zip(line1, line2)]

used = []
for l1 in lines:
    if l1 in used: continue
    for l2 in lines:
        if l2 in used: continue
        if l1 is l2: continue
        if (abs(l1[0] - l2[0]) < 20) and (abs(l1[1] - l2[1]) < 1):
            lines_.append(midline(l1, l2))
            used.append(l1)
            used.append(l2)
            continue
lines = lines_
```

[image]

Now, let's create binary masks for our straight lines. For every straight line, we create a temporary binary black image (all the pixel values are zeros), then draw the line over it as a thick white line (same or slightly thicker than the lines on the original image). Then we logical-AND the original thresholded image and the temporary line image, so we get the pixels common for both - that is the binary mask for the line.

```
line_masks = []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    line_img = np.zeros(bw.shape)
    draw_line(line_img, line, 255, 10) # 10 pixel thick white line
    common = np.logical_and((bw != 0), (line_img != 0))
    line_masks.append(common)
```

Remove the masked pixels from the original black and white image, so only the arcs should remain. Unfortunately, some garbage remains, because the lines in the original image aren't perfect. To get rid of that, we could've drawn our Hough lines thicker (say, 15, or 20 pixels instead of 10), but then they take too much of the arc pixels. Instead, we could erode-dilate the resulting image a little, to get rid of the junk:

```
for lm in line_masks:
    bw[lm] = 0

bw = cv2.erode(bw, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
bw = cv2.dilate(bw, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
```

[image]

Let's create binary masks for the arcs. There's no function in OpenCV to detect arcs, but for this case we could use detection of connected components:

```
arc_masks = []
num, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(bw)
for i in range(1, num):
    arc_masks.append(labels == i)
```

Now that we have the masks, let's visualize them by drawing over the original image. Lines are going to have random shades of green, arcs - of blue:

```
line_colors = [(0, random.randint(127, 256), 0) for _ in line_masks]
arc_colors = [(random.randint(127, 256), 0, 0) for _ in arc_masks]
dst = cv2.imread("s34I0.png")
for color, mask in zip(line_colors, line_masks):
    dst[mask] = color

for color, mask in zip(arc_colors, arc_masks):
    dst[mask] = color
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting approach, i'll try it asap, thanks for the help dude!
Is there anyway I can split the two detected "arcs" (alias not lines) in order to have two separate lists of points?

Comment: The arcs are split already by the code above (in `arc_masks` there are two separate masks, one for each arc, similar to `line_masks` having four separate masks, one for each line).